# Creating dynamic ui with InsertUI in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create dynamic UI with insertUI function. I want to generate the ui to the length of a dataframe. How to use insertUI with loop in R?

Actually I have a Question series, consisting of Categories, Sub-Categories, options. I want to show the user Categories first, which when selected, shows its relevant Sub-category. When the sub-Category is selected, it shows the relevant Question and it's answer. Most importantly, when 1st question is finished, automatically next question is shown with relevant answer and it continues till the end. I am trying to use

my df is like this-

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C","D", "D"), 
      Subcategory = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "C_1", "C_2", "D_3", "D_4"), 
         Option = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
                 


for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])
{  
  if(a==df[i])
  {
    a[i]<-print(paste(df$Category[i], sep = "/n")) 
    
    insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
             ui=  wellPanel(
                           p(a[1])), immediate = TRUE)
 }
}
```

Comment: [this app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html) shows how to create a UI in a loop. Instead of renderUI you can use insertUI

Comment: I had gone through this one. But my requirement is different one. I have to generate ui from a dataframe based on conditions.

Comment: maybe you would be more interested by [renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderUI.html)  more documentation [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#programming-ui)

Comment: in general, it is advisable to use `lapply` instead of `for` loops in `shiny`, because this works better together with the reactivity. Please provide a MRE and show what you've tried so far, so we can better help you. Thanks!

Comment: @starja kindly check my quest again. I updated it..

Comment: @AnkushRana your code is not a MRE, it's difficult to help you now

Comment: @ginberg, my app is quite large therefore not sure how to provide MRE. But my case is this only. I want to create insertUi with lapply function based on conditions.